# Determinant of a tridiagonal matrix with a superdiagonal of ones and a subdiagonal of minus ones

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, tridiagonal-matrices

$$ D_n = \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots& 0 & 0\\
-1& a_2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & a_3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{n-1} & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & a_n
 \end{vmatrix} $$
I thought to multiply last column with $\frac{1}{a_n}$ and add it to the (n-1)-th column and so on but $a_n$ can be equal to $0$.

Comment: The answer has to be a polynomial in $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$.  If you get a solution that works for nonzero $a_n$ in the form of such a polynomial, it will be valid for $a_n=0$ as well.

Comment: You matrix is a tri-diagonal matrix and its determinant can be computed using a 3-term recurrence relation $D_n = a_n D_{n-1} + D_{n-2}$. see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant).

Comment: @achille hui thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $$
D_n = \prod_{k=1}^n a_n \left( 1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{a_ia_{i-1}}\right)
$$
The way to do this is to let 
$$
E_n = \frac{D_n}{\prod_{k=1}^n a_n}
$$
and use Achille hui's insight to get 
$$
E_k = E_{k-1}+\frac{1}{a_{k-1}a_{k-2}}
$$
for all $3 \leq k \leq n$ and sum up.  You have to be careful dealing with the endpopints; I think I got them right but you should check this.